# Create line shapefile that starts at a given point(lat,lon), has a specific angle/slope and truncate it when it overlaps a polygon shapefile

Tags: r, geospatial, trigonometry, spatial, shapefile

###---------- UPDATED ------------###

I need to create a line shapefile with a specific length, that starts at the specified point and makes a certain angle. Then, truncate it when it intersects a polygon so I can measure the distance from the initial point till the polygon.
I need to do this in R.

**Polygons_sf** is just a polygon shapefile of the Azores Islands.
**sightsLand** is a point shapefile w/ different points at sea from which the new line should start.

Code below.
I am just creating a new line from a point at a certain angle (radial_line_sf). Now I only need to truncate the new line when it overlaps with the polygon shapefile (see picture below), which I didn't manage to do yet.

```
# Load required packages
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

# shapefiles
polygon_sf <- read_sf("CAOP_RAA_2022-shp/ArqAcores/ArqAcores_GCentral_AAd_CAOP2022.shp")
polygon_sf <- st_transform(polygon_sf, crs = 4326)
st_crs(polygon_sf)

sights <- read_sf("Sightings.shp")
sightsLand <- subset(sights, sights$RetclLn == "LA")

# Extract lat and lon from the POINT geometry
point_location <- st_coordinates(sightsLand[1, "geometry"])

# Create a single radial line
angle_degrees <- 55  # Specify the angle
line_length <- 0.25  # Adjust the length as needed
angle_rad <- angle_degrees * (pi / 180)  # Convert degrees to radians
end_lat <- point_location[2] + line_length * sin(angle_rad)
end_lon <- point_location[1] + line_length * cos(angle_rad)

#matrix_coords <- rbind(c(point_location[2], end_lon), c(point_location[1], end_lat))
matrix_coords <- rbind(c(point_location[1], point_location[2]), c(end_lon, end_lat))
#matrix_coords <- matrix(c(point_location[2], point_location[1], end_lon, end_lat), ncol = 2)
radial_line_sf <- st_sfc(st_linestring(matrix_coords), crs = 4326)
#radial_line_sf <- st_as_sf(data.frame(matrix_coords), coords = c("X1", "X2"), crs = 4326)

# Plot the polygon, point, and radial line
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = polygon_sf, fill = "lightblue", color = "black") +
  geom_sf(data = sightsLand[1,28], color = "red", size = 3, shape = 18) +
  geom_sf(data = radial_line_sf, color = "blue") +
  theme_minimal()
```

I get the following map using ggplot:
[image]

###---------- 2ND UPDATE ------------###

How to get new linestring shapefile:

```
# Cut line
line_not_overlapping <- lwgeom::st_split(radial_line_sf, polygon_sf)

# Extract the first LineString from the GEOMETRYCOLLECTION
first_line <- line_not_overlapping[[1]][[1]]

# Create a new sf object for the first LineString
first_line_sf <- st_sf(geometry = st_sfc(first_line))

# Set the same CRS as the original line_not_overlapping
st_crs(first_line_sf) <- st_crs(line_not_overlapping)
```

[image]

Comment: Please give us enough information to understand your problem. Sample data in reproducible format would help. Perhaps also a sketch of exactly what you mean. Otherwise, there is a high chance that someone here could spend a fair bit of time and effort in an attempt to answer, only for the answer to be not what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @AllanCameron! I updated the question. Hope it is more clear what my goal is. It changed quite a bit because I'm trying a new approach to solve the problem. Also added what I managed to do so far.

Comment: If answer is too generic and does not fit your use case, please consider providing a reproducible data sample, a single simplified (island) polygon from your shapefile as a dput output ( `dput(polygon_sf[1,])` ) along with point(s) or something constructed from  `sf` North Carolina example dataset, `st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lwgeom::st_split()` to split the line with a polygon; if you extract just the first item from the resulting geometry collection, you'll get the segment that starts from the predefined point (yellow section):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.6.2, PROJ 9.2.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

# example geometries, starting point for the linestring is (1,1)
poly <- st_point(c(5,5)) |> st_buffer(2)
line_1 <- st_linestring(matrix(c(1,1,9,9), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))

# split line by polygon, returns collection of 3 linestrings, keep the first
line_2 <- lwgeom::st_split(line_1, poly)[[1]]

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = poly, fill = NA, color = "darkgreen", linewidth = 1) +
  geom_sf(data = line_2, color = "gold", linewidth = 4) +
  geom_sf(data = line_1, color = "darkblue", linewidth = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:10, expand = expansion(add = 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 0:10, expand = expansion(add = 1)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: using st_split worked; added the code on the post. Thanks for the help